# How to control the width of the menu different Android versions/telephone models?

Tags: android, user-interface

I came across the following problem while testing my application on different devices: while in some there is a thin black container on the top, holding the icons (wifi connection and so on), in others there isn't. In that case the screen starts directly from the top ([image: as you may see HERE]). The telephone here is Nexus, Android 6, API 23.

Styles:

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/barTheme</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/gray_600</item>
    <!--changes the dots button-->
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/gray_200</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Can you please post your AppTheme definition? Do you have different version of style folder for api level 23 ?

Comment: @elvisrusu, no, I don't have a different version of style for api 23. Thank you, I'll read a little bit more for the case, the problem must be coming from there

Comment: Check for windowActionModeOverlay=true in your styles. Seems like the status bar is being drawn on top of your activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely due to the attributes `fitSystemWindows="true"` on some of the root views in your layouts. This causes the odd response on different devices because only recent android versions (I think it came about on android 5.0) have supported content under the status bar, and older devices will simply ignore this new attribute and display content starting under the status bar.

Comment: Thank you! That was the solution - I had a definition  <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item> in the styles(v.21) folder.